# Specify KSQL Stream Subject names explicitly

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

I have two KSQL topics `my-topic-1` and `my-topic-2`, with messages serialised via AVRO. For historical reasons, the `my-topic-1` schema is not in the recommended `topic-value` format, but is instead `my-custom-subject-name`.

I want to move records from one topic to the other via KSQL.

First up, let's create a stream:

```sql
CREATE STREAM my-stream-1
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my-topic-1', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

oops:

```
Avro schema for message values on topic my-topic-1 does not exist in the Schema Registry.
Subject: my-topic-1-value

Possible causes include:
- The topic itself does not exist
        -> Use SHOW TOPICS; to check
- Messages on the topic are not Avro serialized
        -> Use PRINT 'my-topic-1' FROM BEGINNING; to verify
- Messages on the topic have not been serialized using the Confluent Schema Registry Avro serializer
        -> See https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html
- The schema is registered on a different instance of the Schema Registry
        -> Use the REST API to list available subjects
        https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html#get--subjects
```

It's looking for the subject `my-topic-1-value`

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible? `VALUE_AVRO_SCHEMA_FULL_NAME` mentioned [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/avro-schema.html#using-avro-in-ksql) doesn't do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. I've updated https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3188 with an example to reproduce. I suggest we track it there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106782/confluent-ksqldb-can-not-create-stream