# confluent ksqlDB can not create stream

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I want to create stream for users topics

[image]

but , ksqlDB can not create stream.

[image]

[Specify KSQL Stream Subject names explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194102/specify-ksql-stream-subject-names-explicitly)

Comment: How have you populated the `users` topic? Does the schema exist in the Schema Registry?

Comment: BTW it's much easier for people to help if you put the text from the CLI into your question directly, instead of images :)

Comment: Does the schema exist in the Schema Registry? what is this?

Comment: If you're specifying `VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'` then the data needs to be serialised with the Avro serialiser which places the schema in the Schema Registry.

Comment: I use mysql database and debezuim for connec kafka to mysql. Can JSON format instead of AVRO be used everywhere? How?

Comment: after print topic in ksqldb 
Key format: HOPPING(KAFKA_INT) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_INT) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of your source connector configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a schema with subject name "user-value" in Schema Registry first, then your can create the stream.
For how to post schema to Schema Registry, please visit https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/using.html